# Python function with keyword argument accepts positional argument

Tags: python-3.x

Why does this work?

Function `test` accepts a positional argument despite the function defining a keyword argument.

```
>>> def test(a=[]):
...  print(a)
... 
>>> test([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont supply the keyword in your call, it's basically just a positional argument (e.g. order matters) but with a default value if you don't supply a value. However, * can be used like in `test_2` to enforce keyword only arguments.

```
def test_1(a=[], b=1): print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
def test_2(*, a=[]): print(a)
def test_3(x, y): print(x, y) 

test_1([1, 2, 3])
a = [1, 2, 3], b = 1

test_1(2, [1, 2, 3]) 
a = 2, b = [1, 2, 3]  # order of arguments matter.

test_1(b=2, a=[1, 2, 3])
a = [1, 2, 3], b = 2 # order of arguments does not matter.

test_2('a') 
test_2() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

test_3(y='a', x='b') # order does not matter                                                                                                                                                           
b a

test_3('a', 'b') # order matters                                                                                                                                                      
a b
```

**Update (in case someone comes here by googling or whatever):**

[Argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) =/= [Parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter)

Comment: Pretty interesting observations, is there any reference to this in the docs?

Comment: Just from the glossary [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) from what i've found

Answer (score 2):

In Python arguments before *args and / ([PEP570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)) can be used as both positional argument and keyword argument. 
In your case, you have to write like this to force get `a` as a keyword argument.

```
>>> def test(*args,a=[]):
...  print(a)
... 
>>> test([1,2,3])
[]
>>> test(a=[1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

For more information, you can read this python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions).